# Bootstrapping subsampling analysis

Tags: bootstrap

I am currently working on a bootstrapping subsampling analysis, aiming to match a dyslexia group with a comparison group based on their reading achievement scores using PSAboot: Bootstrapping for Propensity Score Analysis in R.

Here is my code snippet for the analysis: enter image description here
[image]

Unfortunately, I've encountered an error that says: '100 bootstrap samples using 1 method. Bootstrap sample sizes: Treated=695 (100%) without replacement. Control=6882 (100%) without replacement. Error in cut.default(ps, quantile(ps, seq(0, 1, 1/nstrata)), include.lowest = TRUE, : 'breaks' are not unique'

I've attempted various methods like applying quantile() inside the unique() function, using jitter, decile, and The .bincode function, but none of them seem to resolve the issue. If you have any suggestions or insights to help me address this problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much.